# How to find and replace an item which bounded by at least one letter and no numbers?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace all of the `-`'s in a document with `\texthyphen ', but only if it is bounded by at least one letter, either before, or after, but not if before or after happens to be a number. E.g.:

- `A-B` becomes `A\texthyphen B`.
- `a-b` becomes `a\texthyphen b`.
- `%-b` becomes `%\texthyphen b`.
- `%-%` is unchanged, because it is not near any letter.
- `1-2` is unchanged, because it is near numbers.
- `A-2` is unchanged, because it is near one number.

How can I replace the hyphens with `\texthyphen`, but only when next to a letter and never when next to a number?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)-\([^[:digit:]]\)/\1\\texthyphen \2/g' -e 's/\([^[:digit:]]\)-\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\\texthyphen \2/g' -e 's/^-\([:alpha:]\)/\\texthyphen \1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across `ssed` (super `sed`) that can handle Perl-like regex. It should be available on Debian-like systems, not sure about the others.

```
$ echo '    A-B becomes A\texthyphen B.
    a-b becomes a\texthyphen b.
    %-b becomes %\texthyphen b.
    %-% is unchanged, because it is not near any letter.
    1-2 is unchanged, because it is near numbers.
    A-2 is unchanged, because it is near one number.' | \
> ssed -R 's/(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?![0-9])|(?<![0-9])-(?=[A-Za-z])/\\texthyphen /g'
```

gives

```
    A\texthyphen B becomes A\texthyphen B.
    a\texthyphen b becomes a\texthyphen b.
    %\texthyphen b becomes %\texthyphen b.
    %-% is unchanged, because it is not near any letter.
    1-2 is unchanged, because it is near numbers.
    A-2 is unchanged, because it is near one number.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)-\([^[:digit:]]\)\|\([^[:digit:]]\)-\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\3\\texthyphen \2\4/g' file
```